# Angular MVC SPA Loops Downloading scripts files

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem I can't seem to figure out. My MVC angular app suddenly started looping in fiddler downloading all the script files repeatedly.

I can stop it by removing my latest addition but I can't see anything wrong with my new angular js file.

Here is a sample from Fiddler:

```
/Scripts/kendo/2015.3.1111/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js?_=1453249603004
/Scripts/kendo.modernizr.custom.js?_=1453249603005
/Scripts/bootstrap/3.3.6/bootstrap.min.js?_=1453249603006
/Angular/js/app-MainNav.js?_=1453249603007
/Angular/js/app-SubNav.js?_=1453249603008

/Scripts/jquery-2.2.0.min.js?_=1453249603010
/Scripts/Angular/1.4.8/angular.min.js?_=1453249603011
/Scripts/Angular/1.4.8/angular-route.min.js?_=1453249603012
/Scripts/kendo/2015.3.1111/jquery.min.js?_=1453249603013
/Scripts/kendo/2015.3.1111/jszip.min.js?_=1453249603014
/Scripts/kendo/2015.3.1111/kendo.all.min.js?_=1453249603015
/Scripts/kendo/2015.3.1111/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js?_=1453249603016
/Scripts/kendo.modernizr.custom.js?_=1453249603017
/Scripts/bootstrap/3.3.6/bootstrap.min.js?_=1453249603018
/Angular/js/app-MainNav.js?_=1453249603019
/Angular/js/app-SubNav.js?_=1453249603020

/Scripts/jquery-2.2.0.min.js?_=1453249603022
/Scripts/Angular/1.4.8/angular.min.js?_=1453249603023
/Scripts/Angular/1.4.8/angular-route.min.js?_=1453249603024
/Scripts/kendo/2015.3.1111/jquery.min.js?_=1453249603025
/Scripts/kendo/2015.3.1111/jszip.min.js?_=1453249603026
/Scripts/kendo/2015.3.1111/kendo.all.min.js?_=1453249603027
/Scripts/kendo/2015.3.1111/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js?_=1453249603028
/Scripts/kendo.modernizr.custom.js?_=1453249603029
/Scripts/bootstrap/3.3.6/bootstrap.min.js?_=1453249603030
/Angular/js/app-MainNav.js?_=1453249603031
/Angular/js/app-SubNav.js?_=1453249603032

/Scripts/jquery-2.2.0.min.js?_=1453249603034
/Scripts/Angular/1.4.8/angular.min.js?_=1453249603035
/Scripts/Angular/1.4.8/angular-route.min.js?_=1453249603036
/Scripts/kendo/2015.3.1111/jquery.min.js?_=1453249603037
/Scripts/kendo/2015.3.1111/jszip.min.js?_=1453249603038
/Scripts/kendo/2015.3.1111/kendo.all.min.js?_=1453249603039
```

The new angular js file:

```
 (function ()
 {
"use-strict";

 angular.module("appMainNav", [])
.directive("dashboardMainNav", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "/Navigation/GetDashItems"
    }
});

})();
```

My custom directive:

```
<div class="row">

<div ng-app="appMainNav" class="col-md-2">
    <dashboard-main-nav></dashboard-main-nav>
</div>

</div>
```

According to fiddler it does call the route but I never hit the breakpoint.
The angular js file is added to the _Layout page.

---

Edit

GetDashItems is an MVC route that takes me to this controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult GetDashItems()
{
    ....snip.....            
  return PartialView("~/Views/Navigation/_MainNav.cshtml", model);
}
```

The cshtml is:
(I used to have @_Layout but removed it thinking that was causing the loop but it made no difference)

```
@model DashboardModel


<nav id="mymlsNavbar" role="navigation">
<div>
     @(Html.Kendo().PanelBar()
    .Name("pnlbr_DashNav")
    .ExpandMode(PanelBarExpandMode.Single)
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:200px" })
    .Items(panelbar =>
    {
        foreach (var dashitm in Model.DashNavigation)
        {
            panelbar.Add()
                    .Expanded(true)
                    .Text(dashitm.Name)
                    .Items(subpnl =>
                    {
                        foreach (var subitm in dashitm.SubDashNav)
                        {
                            subpnl.Add()
                                    .Text(subitm.Name)
                                    .Enabled(!subitm.IsAdvanced)
                                    .url(subitm.Route)
                                    .Route(subitm.Route);
                        }
                    });
        }

    })
    )
</div>
</nav>
```

---

Edit 2.

OK This is getting weird...I'm wondering if this is a VS 2015 bug. I launch it in the debugger and I get the script loop. I immediately kill it. Restart it and no loop and everything works????

I'm going to try in VS2013 and see if it behaves the same. Also publish it to a dev server and see how it behaves.

Comment: Do you need to add ".html" to your templateUrl? I wonder if you're caught in some kind of URL rewrite loop, where "/Navigation/GetDashItems" is resolving to the path of your HTML file that's including those scripts.

Comment: What does the template for `GetDashItems` look like?

Comment: Interesting...technically that is a route but let me see if it has a name overlap.

Comment: A server-side route or Angular router provider route?

Comment: I updated the question with better detail.

Comment: If you comment out the "templateUrl" line, does it stop?